# Как вывести только нужные параметры через subprocess Popen

Tags: python, windows

Если использовать этот код, то выводятся все процессы на компьютере, но мне надо не всё знать об этих процессах, а только id и сколько памяти они занимают. Я никак найти не смог как это сделать не используя библиотеку psutil.

```
    import os
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_output
    print(*[line.decode('cp866', 'ignore') 
    for line in Popen('tasklist', stdout=PIPE).stdout().readlines()])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используем только встроенные модули:

```
import io
import csv
from subprocess import check_output

fh = io.StringIO(check_output(["tasklist", "/fo", "csv"]).decode('cp866', 'ignore'))
reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=",")
for row in reader:
    print(row["PID"], row["Mem Usage"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
import io
import os
import pandas as pd     #  pip install pandas / conda install pandas
from subprocess import check_output

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(check_output(["tasklist", "/fo", "csv"]).decode('cp866', 'ignore')))
```

Результат:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
                 Image Name    PID Session Name  Session# Mem Usage
0       System Idle Process      0     Services         0       8 K
1                    System      4     Services         0   4.548 K
2                  Registry    324     Services         0  86.904 K
3                  smss.exe    932     Services         0     616 K
4                 csrss.exe    992     Services         0   5.352 K
5               wininit.exe   1112     Services         0   6.772 K
6              services.exe   1328     Services         0  10.520 K
..                      ...    ...          ...       ...       ...
227       RuntimeBroker.exe   1128      Console         5  31.268 K
228             svchost.exe  11636     Services         0  16.820 K
229       RuntimeBroker.exe  12296      Console         5  13.088 K
230             svchost.exe   5004     Services         0  25.812 K
231  backgroundTaskHost.exe   9712      Console         5  12.448 K
232       RuntimeBroker.exe  19256      Console         5   8.248 K
233            tasklist.exe  19468      Console         5   7.928 K

[234 rows x 5 columns]
```

Выбираем нужные столбцы:

```
In [18]: df[["PID", "Mem Usage"]]
Out[18]:
       PID Mem Usage
0        0       8 K
1        4   4.548 K
2      324  86.904 K
3      932     616 K
4      992   5.352 K
5     1112   6.772 K
6     1328  10.520 K
..     ...       ...
227   1128  31.268 K
228  11636  16.820 K
229  12296  13.088 K
230   5004  25.812 K
231   9712  12.448 K
232  19256   8.248 K
233  19468   7.928 K

[234 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

или сразу читаем только нужные столбцы:

```
In [19]: cols = ["PID", "Mem Usage"]

In [20]: df = (pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(check_output(["tasklist", "/fo", "csv"])
                                       .decode('cp866', 'ignore')), 
                           usecols=cols))

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
       PID Mem Usage
0        0       8 K
1        4   4.708 K
2      324  83.284 K
3      932     616 K
4      992   5.348 K
5     1112   6.772 K
6     1328  10.424 K
..     ...       ...
222   1128  19.400 K
223  11636  16.856 K
224  12296  11.324 K
225   7664   8.144 K
226   2388  73.392 K
227  20776  13.364 K
228  17908   7.916 K

[229 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Да, действительно всё работает, а нельзя встроенными библиотеками? Например считать это всё через Popen, а потом из него выбрать нужные столбики? Popen вообще предоставляет такую возможность?

Comment: @Pashok, можно парсить CSV встроенным модулем `csv`, но код будет больше и нужно будет использовать цыклы...

Comment: Из [этой](https://python-scripts.com/import-csv-python) статьи я понял, что надо вначале это всё дело в файл записать, а потом из него уже разделить и получить то, что необходимо

Comment: @Pashok, в ответе я показал как можно использовать `io.StringIO` для того чтобы читать строку с данными как файл...